Why is it that if I define a function in the Global Frame, and bind the name __add__ to it, the program does not work? (It's about CS61A course.)
So I'm a non Berkeyley student and I'm using the online book provided by CS61A to learn programming.
In section 2.9 Recursive Objects, I coded character by character as the text specifies, and the Python interpreter give me this error message:
    return with_m + without_m
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "Link") to tuple

I copied and pasted all the demo codes into my .py file, and the same error messages occurs. Looks like Professor John DeNero seems to overlooked something in his code. After I substitute the line the error messages seems to points to to
    return extend_link(with_m, without_m)

The code is running OK!
I wonder why because the only change I make is to substitude a class method with its definition.
This is the original code:
class Link:
    """A linked list with a first element and the rest."""
    empty = ()
    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i == 0:
            return self.first
        else:
            return self.rest[i-1]
    def __len__(self):
        return 1 + len(self.rest)

def extend_link(s, t):
    if s is Link.empty:
        return t
    else:
        return Link(s.first, extend_link(s.rest, t))

Link.__add__ = extend_link

def partitions(n, m):
    """Return a linked list of partitions of n using parts of up to m.
    Each partition is represented as a linked list.
    """
    if n == 0:
        return Link(Link.empty) # A list containing the empty partition
    elif n < 0 or m == 0:
        return Link.empty
    else:
        using_m = partitions(n-m, m)
        with_m = map_link(lambda s: Link(m, s), using_m)
        without_m = partitions(n, m-1)
**        return with_m + without_m**

The line with bold face is the line of code the interpreter points to. After I substitude return with_m + without_m with extend_link(with_m, without_m), the code works fine!
So imo I'm basically changing the name "+" to its actual definition, why is it wrong?
What's more interesting is that, in the following code
s = Link(3, Link(4, Link(5)))
s + s

it also works!!!
Why is that? I'm confused.
It's my first my asking on stackoverflow. Hope you don't mind my chaotic phrasing of sentences and confusing logic and broken English. Thanks everybody who sees this. I would very much appreciate your help.
I tried substitute the name "+" with its exact definition, and it works fine.
I also tried s + s, and it also works fine.
From the error message, I guess that in the following line:
def partitions(n, m):
    """Return a linked list of partitions of n using parts of up to m.
    Each partition is represented as a linked list.
    """
    if n == 0:
        return Link(Link.empty) # A list containing the empty partition
    elif n < 0 or m == 0:
        **return Link.empty**
    else:
        using_m = partitions(n-m, m)
        with_m = map_link(lambda s: Link(m, s), using_m)
        without_m = partitions(n, m-1)
        return with_m + without_m

When one side of the operator + is Link.empty, which is indeed a tuple, we are actually "adding List to tuple", which is exactly what the error message is saying.
But Why  is that I can get around this problem by simply changing the name "+" to its actual definition?
Thanks y'll. I appreciate your help.

What is map_link? It appears that with_m is a tuple, not an instance of Link. (extend_link doesn't care if its first argument isn't a Link, but with_m + without_m isn't actually invoking it if with_m is a tuple.)

This has nothing to do with defining the function in the global scope. You'd have the same problem if you defined __add__ as a method in the class itself.

@Barmar, thanks sir. I think I've got that.

For future viewers's information, I think @chepner's answer perfectly pinpointed my problem. Basically my problem is that when the base case in the function partitions(n, m) is reached, i.e. elif n < 0 or m == 0:  return Link.empty, the "+" operator is not invoking the extend_link function that I defined.

@chepner On my god. Thanks so much, sir. I weren't aware of that. I think your answer perfectly solved my problem. Also, map_link is defined as: def map_link(f, s): if s is Link.empty: return s else: return Link(f(s.first), map_link(f, s.rest)) So basically, if the argument to map_link is a tuple, the return value is the tuple itself, which explains why "+" is not invoking the extend_link function in my case. I should be more cautious and think my program through line by line before asking other people stupid questions.
